# Sort Text and Number in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to some how create a Macro or some kind of function to sort Column B with PT- first then PC- then the number form smallest to largest
Exp: PT-1,PT-2,PT-3,PC-1,PC-2,PC-3.
[image: My Work Sheet]

I want it to look like this
[image]

Comment: perhaps a helper column to find and label items in the order you require.

Comment: Is there a tutorial how to set it up. I am still quite new to VBA

Answer (score 1):

VBA is not needed for this. You can use the built in sorting functionality but because `PC` comes before `PT` alphabetically, you need a helper column where `PT` is transformed into something that comes before `PC`.

You can use `SUBSTITUTE` to replace the `T` with `A` and then sort by this helper column.

[image]

The formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE([@Your_Column_Name],"T","A")
```